# Enter Button Not Taking To New Line In Output Box Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I Wrote A Code In Which Every Changes Made In Input Box Is Reflected In Output Box And Working Fine Also But Problem Is When I Press Enter To Go To New Line in Output Box It Is Not Going To New Line Unless Length Of Line Ends.

```js
var App =React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
        return{
            value:"My Value"
        }
    },
    updateValue:function(modifiedValue){
        this.setState({
            value:modifiedValue
        })
    },
    render:function(){
        return(
            <div className="inputBox container-fluid">
                <h1 className="text-center text-primary">Hello Coders !!!</h1>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1"><InputBox value={this.state.value} updateValue={this.updateValue}/></div>
                    <div  className="outputBox col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">{this.state.value}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
var InputBox =React.createClass({
    update:function(){
      //  var modifiedValue=ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.initialValue).value;
        var modifiedValue=this.refs.initialValue.value;
       // var modifiedValue= e.target.value
        this.props.updateValue(modifiedValue);
    },
    render:function(){
        return(
        <textarea type="text" value={this.props.value} onChange={this.update} ref="initialValue">
                        </textarea>

        );
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<App />,
document.querySelector("#app")
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>React Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .outputBox,textarea{
            width: 400px;
            border: 5px solid gray;
            margin: 0;
            height: 500px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="demo.js" type="text/babel"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.2/marked.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can try use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` like this https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/32970/, because in `textarea` enter has symbol `\n` but for html you must use `<br>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Directed By @Alexander Instead Using Like

```js
<div  className="outputBox col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">{this.state.value}</div>
```

Added

```js
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ this.format(this.state.value) } />
```

And

```js
format: function (value) {
     return { __html: value.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br>') };
    },
And It Worked
```